# Problems installing java application with install4j on debian Xfce system

Tags: java, jar, debian, install4j

I´m trying to install a commercial java application which comes with a *install4j* setup on a fresh Debian 9.3 VM (AMD64) running Xfce.

```
# chmod +x setupLinux.sh
# ./setupLinux.sh -J- DJava.awt.headless=true
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Container    
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:67)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.ConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(ConsoleScreenExecutor.java:24)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerConsoleScreenExecutor.java:6)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:92)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:58)
at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

[According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117541/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-awt-container)  I Installed lib32z1 and lib32ncurses5 as ia32-libs are not available anymore.

I´ve installed [LibXtst](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355914/8896140) as mentioned in this post.

```
# locate libXtst
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6  
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6  
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

but the error persists.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers

Edit 2:
The application comes bundled with Oracle-Java 8.x.
The server has:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

My dear, sorry

starting with no parameters brought up

```
./setupLinux.sh /?
Unpacking JRE ...
Preparing JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/stefan/Dokumente/Temp/setupLinux.sh.9370.dir/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
```

So:

```
# apt install install libxrender1
```

solved my issue.